# Adding On-Premise node to EKS - Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, architecture, amazon-eks

I am running a machine learning algorithm that needs to run in our own environment due to being using local cameras. We have deployed a non-managed Kubernetes cluster using an EC2 instance and we connect the Worker Nodes to the master using a VPN. The problem with that is that it is not scalable for the way I want it to scale, and honestly, it is a bit of a hassle to deploy a new node.

I was wondering how I can deploy on-premise nodes to EKS or any other suggestion that would make our life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, having on-prem nodes connected to master in Amazon is a wild idea. Nodes should report to master frequently and failure to do so due to Internet hiccups may hurt you badly. I mean, dude, that's really bad idea even if now it goes nice. You should consider installing master locally.

But anyway, how do you connect nodes to master? Every node has its own VPN connection? How many masters you have? Generally, you should set up AWS VPN connection between your VPC and local subnet using IPSec. In that case there is permanent tunnel between the subnets and adding more nodes becomes trivial task depending on how you deployed everything. At least that's how it seems to me.

Comment: The nodes are connected to the master through a VPN. I expect to deploy this solution across 2500+ stores and every node would be connected to the VPN to the same master (easier to manage), but I didn't want to keep using this as it's clearly a not easy infrastructure to maitain.

Comment: 2500 nodes connected to one master node using VPN??? Good luck with that, you are definitely ask for problem. Why not decouple VPN functionality from master node?